# Repeating groups of controls - Sample code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

I want to create a Windows Form in VB .NET (using VS 2012) that has this behaviour:

1. It is a standalone desktop application for data entry
2. All data is stored in a local CSV file - there is no database & no editing of previous data
3. The form allows a user to enter data in rows of fields - text boxes, combo boxes, dates
4. Each row is a set of data and corresponds to a line of data in the CSV file
5. The user can add or remove lines by clicking [+] or [-] buttons - one pair per line

I can easily build an app that satisfies 1 - 4.  Today, I could build my app to enter and save just a single line at a time.

What I want to do now is to enhance the application to number 5 above :

- Group the fields together (in a panel?) - I don't like using a DataGrid for this; it looks better to use a repeating set of simple controls
- Add a group of fields (to a list of panels?)
- Remove a specific line (group of fields)

When the user clicks [Save], I will then gather all the data collected on the form and save it to the CSV file, one file line per group of fields.

Does anyone have some sample code to show how to do something like this?

Can someone suggest the best way to group the fields so they can be repeated?

Comment: I suggest making a user control containing the controls you need and add one of these per line. You can then dock these on the form inside a panel with auto-scrolling on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group each row of controls in a `Panel`, so you  can easily remove them all together when needed, and I suggest you to group all the rows in another `Panel` with scroll bars, so when the number of rows exceed the height doesnt create outside the bounds of the form.

And for the creation and deletion of controls, you have to do it dinamically, adding all the properties needed and handlers (events) with `AddHandler`. You just need to know the position of the new row, just get the last `Panel` added and add the distance from top.

And when deleting a row, just remove the `Panel` and decrease the top of the rest of the panel behind (example supposing you have only panels (rows) on your form):

```
Form1.Controls.RemoveAt(iPos)

For i As Integer = iPos To Panel1.Controls.Count - 1
    Form1.Controls(i).Top -= iDistBetween
Next
```

I hope this can guide you.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  This looks like a lot of work.  Anyone have some sample code?